# redirection of multiple url

Tags: html, url, virtual, host

How i can correctly direct multiple url in a same conf file.let me know if i am correct to put my conf file like this

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
```

ServerName     domain1.com

ServerAlias    domain2.com

```
... real vhost settings ...
   </VirtualHost>
```

and what if user could'nt find the url then he should me directed to a default page.please if anyone can  tell me how i can put a redirection to a defult only if that url is not found.

Comment: Have you looked at the [examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), it explains all of this

Comment: thanks, but that means that whichever vhost is configured first it will bound to call that as primary server but the situation here is if i try to browse www.abc.com and it search for the .conf file and it couldn't find it then it will ask apache then apache's httpd.conf file will open the default page(if i am correct).So my question is how to tell apache that if that url is not present please load www.default.com

Comment: That's right, it'll choose the first vhost. Create a vhost file with a name that will always be selected first, so I named my vhost file `aaaa`, however `000-default` is common.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up apache vhosts like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias *.domain1.com

  ServerAlias domain2.com

  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error404.php

  #... real vhost settings ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

Any not found URL will be redirected to /errors/error404.php, or any URL you give here.
Ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404.

For ServerAlias domain2.com, you must set up first a bind primary zone for this domain in your name server, this cname will point to your server's IP, otherwise, this line will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks, heaps but now situation changed a bit as i am dealing with multiple vhosts and .conf files so my server will take a default one which is listed on top in my vhosts directory and browse to that webpage which it directs to,but what i want now is to create a conf file which say something like AAA.conf or default.conf and make sure it will be default one and it only printout on screen that "sorry the webpage you are trying to search is currently unavailable or does not exists" in this way i donot have to create another project with only a page saying this.

Comment: Do you want to add RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com RewriteRule ^.*$ /errors/error404.php [L] (in two lines) ? In your error404.php you say "sorry the webpage...

Comment: actually i want a seperate conf file which i can put as a default conf file in my vhosts directory so that if user try to search an url and iti s not there then it will direct to the default page with the help of that conf file.

Comment: or can i configure the httpd.conf file to handle the redirection and tell apache to direct it to the default webpage if there is no webpage available?